# Need help incorporating a PWM into a circuit

Tags: led, pcb, pcb-design, pwm, led-driver

everyone I hope you're staying safe.
To preface I am a noob at electronics, and I've learned a lot these past weeks. I need help designing with designing a circuit.

To explain my project: I have a [Nichia E21A LED](https://www.cutter.com.au/product/nvswe21at-sm573-d240-m1-r9080/) ([datasheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/bcf4/0900766b815c3e45.pdf)) that needs to be powered by **any** 5v power bank and be user dimmable via dial. The PCB and LED will be housed in different modules.

[image]

I need components to be sourced off of LCSC for convenience. The LED needs to be run at 3.1v @ 700mA for 242 lm. However, after collimation I need around 100 lumens. This is a colour sensitive use so I need to keep the LED running 90% of current output to maintain colour temp, thus needing a PWM for dimming.

My schematics:

[image: What I have so far]
Im using the [BP1361](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Bright-Power-Semicon-BP1361_C80209.pdf) LED driver.

I need the switching controller to fit and able to be mass produced, so no Arduino.

My questions are:

1. Which switching controller do I pick?
2. How do I wire it up according to the schematic?
3. Are my passive component values okay?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome. The datasheet says you can use DC voltage control on the DIM pin, range is 0.5 to 2.5 volt. Or use a TLC555 timer wired for PWM at about 100 KHZ. The BP1361 is the right choice for something so simple.

Comment: @VTNCaGNtdDVNalUy Thank you for your answer. I just spent all this time wiring the TLC555-Q1 up. Only to my surprise the BP1361 has a max dim frequency of 50kHz. And the 555 outputs a minimum of 1.2MHz. Do I need to find another switching controller?

Comment: The 555 has no minimum frequency per se. It has a **maximum frequency** of 1.2 MHZ. The TLC555 has a **maximum frequency** of 2 MHZ.